# Should ELMAH catch Microsoft .NET Framework exceptions?

Tags: iis, elmah, w3wp

I'm using ELMAH to log unhandled exceptions within an MVC 5 application. So far, so good.

Occasionally an IE-crashing error comes up, with the following description:
An unhandled Microsoft .NET Framework exception occurred in w3wp.exe

This error is not reported by ELMAH. Should it be?

More info on error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll
Additional information: Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: '4118' Key being added: '4118'.

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't been able to recreate the error today and I don't have enough rep here yet to post an image . . .

Comment: I really just want to know if ELMAH should be catching it though. . .think I'm onto what's causing it.

Answer (score 1):

No. Elmah should not be catching or logging exceptions that crash w3wp.exe.

w3wp.exe is the process that runs IIS (I believe it stands for World Wide Web Worker Process). When IIS crashes, Elmah crashes along with it.

You may however be able to find more information in the windows error event logs (which you can think of as Elmah for the operating system).